# Checking for Running Process if Errors Out using PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell

My PowerShell code is seeing the process run and every 60 seconds writes a message saying its running - that's working fine.  When I kill the process it keeps writing the "process is running" every sixty seconds - when process has been eliminated.
What is wrong with the logic that would not write an event in the App log - it works if I launch the script and the process is not running at the time of launch.

```
while($true) {
If (( $(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process |findstr "MoveFilesToServer") -eq $null )) 
{
    Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "MoveFilesToServer" -eventID 0018 -EntryType Error -Message "Move files process not running"

}
else { Write-Host 'process is running' } 
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're in an infinite loop with while true:

```
$gwmiArgs = @{
    Class       = 'Win32_Process'
    Filter      = 'CommandLine LIKE "%MoveFilesToServer%"'
    ErrorAction = 'Ignore'
}
while (Get-WmiObject @gwmiArgs) {
    'Process is running.'
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}

$writeEventLogArgs = @{
    LogName   = 'Application'
    Source    = 'MoveFilesToServer'
    EventID   = 18
    EntryType = 'Error'
    Message   = 'Move files process not running!'
}
Write-EventLog @writeEventLogArgs
```

This version will run as long as the process exists and writes to the event log when it doesn't.

Comment: The Process Name appears as 'cmd.exe'  -  the MoveFilesToServer appears in the Commandline which is the reason I've used the FindStr to differentiate                                                  
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
     55       5      576       2724              6940   0 choice
     31       3     1508       2084              2108   0 cmd
     38       4     1628       2756       0.03   6932   5 cmd
     40       4     2164       3288             12324   0 cmd

Comment: first - I need to say that this is powershell script will be launched any running all the time - looping through to check for the process to see if it's running - and if not write to the event log.

Comment: when I run the script I originally created - it is delivering Process is Running.  When I run the version using the @gwmArgs - and using the Write-Host to show Process is Running - it is writing an error to the Event Log - when the process is running.

Comment: Do you plan on restarting the process in the script? or do you want to infinitely populate the event log?  If the process actually contains that commandline, then it will be found. @Configueroa

Comment: the process I'm checking for a run status is launched at system startup via a batch file - I would like to have it call this checker script to check itself - it will continually write to the event log - but our event management software will notify us only once - then it will be restarted by a tech support person

Comment: It sounds like what you want is actually a service and you're using the wrong tool for the job.  Splunk or similar tools that already exist can do what you're requesting.  @Configueroa

Comment: the Write-Host 'process is running' is just debug check to see if it's continually looping - it's just not seeing the not running state